# Data not post in react native

Tags: react-native, wordpress-rest-api

```
**const order = yield call(createOrder, prepareData);
    console.log(order)
    yield put({
      type: Actions.CREATE_ORDER_SUCCESS,
      payload: order,
    });**
```

When I log to the console `prepareData` it gives all data I want like:

```
{
meta_data[],
makeTomeasure:[],
variations:true
}
```

But when I log order all data appear except `makeToMeasure`.

Comment: if would be easy to understand the problem if you can share your source code.

Comment: my code consist of many file relate to that piece i cant do tha

Comment: in createOrder i got api like data=>(my api , data) and data console is same as prepareData but order console did not set maketomeasure map @SDushan